# "jt: command not found"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to change the Jupyter notebook theme, so I installed the themes with:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

The installation seems working fine but when I try to change the theme:

```
jt -t <theme_name>
```

I get:

```
jt: command not found
```

I tried to uninstall the themes:

```
pip uninstall jupyterthemes
```

but I got:

```
Skipping jupyterthemes as it is not installed
```

During the installation I got no error though.

What should I do to install the themes properly?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I installed Jupyter Notebook with pip. Jupyter works fine, it's just the themes that don't work

Comment: Anyone know how to solve this for a user without sudo access?

Comment: `Problem solved installing jupyterthemes with:

sudo -H python3 -m pip install jupyterthemes` Upload it as an answer. If you do that than anyone can get the answer easily

Answer (score 3):

Simply run this. I was facing same issue, it worked
.

```
sudo pip install jupyterthemes
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue without sudo access by inputting commands within a Jupyter notebook.

Input the following in the cell of a notebook:

```
!pip install jupyterthemes
```

`jt` commands should work well afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your bash terminal and execute these commands:

```
$ pip install jupyterthemes
$ ls .local/bin/
$ .local/bin/jt -l
$ .local/bin/jt -t chesterish
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to change the theme from inside the Jupyter notebook just use the below code.

```
!jt -l   # to see the list of available themes

!jt -t <theme_name>   # to set a theme
```

For example:

```
!jt -t monokai
```