# command jt jupyterthemes not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use jupyterthemes on jupyter notebook. The version of python that I have is the 3.6.2 of 64 bits, on windows 7. The version of jupyter that I am using is 5.3.1 and my version of pip is 10.0.1.

To launch jupyter I use the following command line

```
py -m notebook
```

I'm trying to do the following

```
py -m jt -t
jt -t
```

But some way to use the `jt` command does not work. Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["jt: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009119/jt-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `!` sign as shown below:

```
! jt -t
```