# Changing Jupyter Notebook Theme: "NameError: name 'jt' is not defined"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I ran this command:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

But when I want to list the themes, anything with `jt`,

```
jt -l
```

It returns this error:

```
NameError: name 'jt' is not defined
```

I have restarted my jupyter notebook but it still gives the above error. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["jt: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009119/jt-command-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Terminal commands can be executed in Jupyter Notebook cells by prepending an exclamation mark (`!`) to the beginning of the command.

To fix the error simply run: `! jt -l`