# NameError: name 'jt' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter

I want to change my jupyter notebook theme back to default. But it is always showing:
NameError: name 'jt' is not defined. I have uploaded the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oz0I.png) of my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["jt: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50009119/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command you are using is wrong try this,

## install jupyterthemes

- pip install jupyterthemes

## upgrade to latest version

- pip install --upgrade jupyterthemes

Once you install use

- !jt -l

Now you should be able to list Jupiter Themes